# Update Statement will not update table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to update a vendor record in a MS Access table and this is the code if have in the DA layer:

method to update the vendor

```
public static void updateVendor(Vendor aVendor)
{
    try
    {
        String sSQLCommand = "UPDATE Vendor SET VendorID = '" + aVendor.VendorId + "', VendorName = '" + aVendor.Name 
                            + "', AddressNo = '" + aVendor.AddressNo + "', Address = '" + aVendor.Address + "', City = '" 
                            + aVendor.City + "', State = '" + aVendor.State + "', ZipCode = '" + aVendor.Zipcode + "', PhoneNumber = '" 
                            + aVendor.PhoneNumber + "' WHERE VendorID = '" + aVendor.VendorId + "'";

        // Create the command object
        if (aConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            aConnection.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = aConnection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sSQLCommand;
        // Execute the SQL command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        aConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any kind of error, but it will not update the table, so I'm not sure what is wrong about it, do you see anything that is wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be concatenating SQL like that - your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Did you check what `sSQLCommand` is before execution? Did you try executing it directly?

Comment: not sure, but you don't need to/shouldn't set VendorID = '...'.

Comment: Also poor form on the connection sharing. `OleDbConnection` supports connection pooling, so you ought to create a new one whenever you need a connection, within a `using` statement, rather than sharing a single instance (`aConnection`) between multiple methods.

Comment: @Oded how should my SQL be then? And yea sSQLCommand has the right statement in it, or at least what I think is right, because it's not working

Comment: @Phil alright, I took the VendorID part out

Comment: You should use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead of concatenation.

Comment: Are all the fields in the `Vendor` table strings? If any of them are integers, perhaps you should remove the single quotes for those.

Comment: @Oded thanks for the link ill try and change the SQL.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge they're all strings

Comment: i figured it out. I had an input mask on the vendorId column in Access as: \V####, so the ID was really just the four numbers, but it was searching for V#### so it just never found the record to update

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, if the query is executing without any error and the issue is that no record is updated then check following in data:

- VendorID field is text field, so if it's having white space preceding the value in the column then your query will not update any thing but execute successfully.

It's possible because access does n't remove the preceding white space in text.